# how to fix Cors problem in this example with Visual Studio Code

Tags: html

I'm having a problem with CORS in this example html page.
Specifically, I have the following error:

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I have seen several solutions, but I have not found the right one.

Here's how I changed the code without success.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="id01"></div>

<script crossorigin="anonymous | use-credentials">
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "https://xzssfrhno7.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/items/aabbccdd234";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    myFunction(myArr);
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(arr) {
  var out = "";
  var i;
  for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    out += '<a href="' + arr[i].url + '">' + 
    arr[i].display + '</a><br>';
  }
  document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cors has to be  resolved on the server side ... Seems you are fetching from an aws API gateway. Enable cors there